# JavaScript JQuery hide/show function

Tags: javascript, jquery

so lately i have been working on a little bit of js.

so, basically, my problem is that i need to hide whatever is passed in the parameters or show it if it already hidden.

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
function toggleReport(table){
//the table argument is the table's id
alert(table);                    //to check that the name of the table is right
if($('#table').is(':visible')){ //check if visible
    $('#table').hide();     //if so, hide it
    alert('hide');          //send a message that it is now being hidden
}else{                          //if already hidden
alert('show');                  //send a message that it is now being shown
$('#table').show();             //show the table
}

}
//-->
</script>
```

however, it doesn't work.... it is sending the alerts, and everything is correct, however, it does not hide or show the table....

but, if i try doing this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
function toggleReport(){
//removed the argument
alert('table_1');
if($('#table_1').is(':visible')){
    $('#table_1').hide();
    alert('hide');
}else{
alert('show');
$('#table_1').show();
}

}
//-->
</script>
```

It works! why is it like that? because im going to have many tables on the website and other things that need to be hidden and shown and i dont want to make a new function for each.. :/

Please help me!

THANKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Simple use **toggle()** intead of show()/hide(), **toggle()** makes element visible if it is hide and hide it if it is visible.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>;
function toggleReport(element_ID){
$("#"+element_ID).toggle();
}
</script>
```

If you want to hard code the Element ID than use following script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggleReport(){
$("#table_1").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Cheers, and dont forgot to vote up my answer
:)

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing an element reference in, use that as your selector:

```
function toggleReport(table){
    $(table).toggle();
}
```

Note I'm using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which will do exactly what you're attempting to do manually. If you wanted to log the new state, you can do so in the callback:

```
function toggleReport( table ) {
    $( table ).toggle('fast', function(){
        console.log( "Element is visible? " + $(this).is(":visible") );
    });
}
```

Note, if you're passing in the ID of the element, your selector will need to be modified:

```
$( "#" + table ).toggle();
```

Comment: thanks, but what do i pass in the parameters of toggle? my table is from a class that i made in css called 'hidden', and the display is equal to none over there, now how do i make toggle to toggle it on and off? and sorry if my question sounds stupid.. im pretty new to js..

Comment: @Baruch jQuery will handle that for you - don't worry about the CSS. Just call `$(table).toggle()`, where `table` is the reference to your element.

Comment: @Baruch in the example provided here you should be passing a reference to the DOM element you wish to show/hide. It could be "raw" or an already selected jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a prebuilt Jquery function for this.](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to achieve this....

```
$(selector).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/uW3cN/2/

**demo with parameter passed** http://jsfiddle.net/uW3cN/3/

Good read API toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**code**

```
function toggleReport(){
//removed the argument
$('#table_1').toggle();

}
```

​**another sample** rest html is in here http://jsfiddle.net/uW3cN/3/

```
function toggleReport(tableid){
//removed the argument
$('#'+tableid).toggle();

}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made in your original function is that you did not actually use the parameter you passed into your function.You selected `"#table"` which is simply selecting a element on the page with the id "table". It didn't reference your variable at all.

If your intention was to pass an ID into the selector should be written, `jQuery("#" + table)`. If table is instead a reference to a DOM element, you would write `jQuery(table)` (no quotes and no pound sign).